# Expressions inside C# 8 switch

Tags: c#, switch-statement, c#-8.0

I'd like to be able to call a method/local function from within the new C# switch expression pattern matching.

Here's an example I've got:

```
        string result = value switch
        {
            IsFizz(value) => "Fizz",
            IsBuzz(value) => "Buzz",
            (IsFizz(value) && IsBuzz(value)) => "FizzBuzz",
            _ => value.ToString()
        };
```

However I get the follow errors:

> A single-element deconstruct pattern requires some other syntax for
> disambiguation. It is recommended to add a discard designator '_'
> after the close paren ')'.
>
> Sytnax error, '=>' expected
>
> Invalid expression term '&&'

Is it not possible to use new the switches in this manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but in the `when` clause:

```cs
        string result = value switch
        {
            _ when IsFizz(value) => "Fizz",
            _ when IsBuzz(value) => "Buzz",
            _ when (IsFizz(value) && IsBuzz(value)) => "FizzBuzz",
            _ => value.ToString()
        };
```

(shouldn't the `FizzBuzz` test come first?)

Comment: Interesting - I'm surprised the discard is necessary. I wonder if this indicates that using a switch expression here isn't the right choice.

Comment: I'd agree with @user9993 comment.  It seems that you can get the same in a more compact form and just as 'readable' using the "? : " ternary if-then-else `        string result = 
            IsFizz(value) ? "Fizz" :
            IsBuzz(value) ? "Buzz" :
            IsFizz(value) && IsBuzz(value) ? "FizzBuzz" :
            value.ToString();'